# Microsoft Power BI connect to mysql

Tags: powerbi

My mysql server is on the cloud. I install the connector to connect mysql on **Window 7** machine. Then I try to connect from Power BI to MySQL server. I give the IP address and database name, my root credential. Then I click on save. It gives me the following error.

> ```
> DataSource.Error: MySQL: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
> Details:
>     Message=Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
>     ErrorCode=-2147467259
> ```

Then I try to connect from mysql workbench with the same credential from the same machine. I can connect, but I am not connecting from Excel Power BI.

Answer (score 5):

I found that you need to install a special driver to get PowerBi to work with MySQL. The link to that driver is actually in the error message (but you can't click on it or select the text?). 
[image]

> mysql-connector-net-6.6.5.msi

[I found the file here.](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=412152)

Comment: its actually nothing but a normal MySQL connector for .net