# Power BI not connecting to AWS MySQL instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, powerbi

I am trying to connect Power BI (Desktop version) with my online Amazon MySQL database. It demands for following information once you try to establish connection

> Server: server IP
>
> Database: database name
>
> Username: MySQL username
>
> Password: MySQL password

First time I received a bit lengthy error, which was because of unavailability of mysql-connector-net-6.6.5.msi. So I followed this link to solve the issue: *[Microsoft Power BI connect to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27618766/microsoft-power-bi-connect-to-mysql)*.

However, after installing the mysql-connector, I am facing another error:

[image]

Whats wrong? One of my mates has successfully connected using the same credentials that I am using.

Comment: make sure you are using basic authentication and not windows in PBI desktop

Comment: @Niraj yes I am using basic authentication. I do select "Database" tab before entering username and password

Comment: @H_Z Did you manage to figure this one out?

Answer (score 6):

I'm able to connect directly to a MySQL database on port 3306. As I understand, it would be more secure to go through an SSH tunnel, but this doesn't work yet with Power BI.

So here are instructions for connecting directly:

**First, let's make sure that everything besides the PowerBI connection is working.**

1. Download and install the correct version of the MySQL/Net Connector.  Right now, version 6.6.5 is the one that works. But from other forums, and from within PowerBI itself, I linked to other versions that did not work  (you will know it isn't working, because you probably won't be able to even open Get Data/MySQL Database/Connect).
2. See if you can connect remotely to your database through some well established utility like MySQL workbench. If you can't,

- look at ports on the remote server. Here's a cool utility to check ports & IPs: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
- Check the permissions of the DB user. Realize that they may be affiliated with an IP address: 'username'@'ipaddress'. So that user can only connect for a particular IP.
- Check the bind address setting. In newer versions of MariaDB, it should probably be commented out. I'm not sure about older version and pure MySQL.
- other troubleshooting.

**So after that's working, here are the settings which worked for me in MySQL:**

go to Get Data/MySQL database/connect

- Server:   ipaddress:3306  (include ":port#")
- Database: dbname

PowerBI interface.  Select "Database" instead of "Windows"
[image: PowerBI interface. Select "Database" instead of "Windows"]

Make sure you select Database instead of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Just a small tip. If you haven't already, restart the machine you just installed the connector on. I had to restart before it started working.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this was to add the port number to the server name/ip

eg. 192.168.0.1:4664